# Xamarin.iOS Automatic provisioning profile not showing up for a colleague with the same app

Tags: xamarin.ios, provisioning-profile

I have no problems building our app for the iOS simulator, with automatic bundle signing and the associated automatic provisioning profile. My settings are:
[image]

But my colleague gets this:
[image]

The system can't find a matching provisioning profile for the automatic signing identity.

What are we missing? My understanding is that he doesn't need an Apple Developer ID or to be part of our Apple Developer Team for automatic signing. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause：**

Since you are using **Manual Provisioning**, your colleague should download the provisioning profile and install on his computer.

**Solution:**

To login Apple account and download certifications with Visual Studio, go to **tools** --> **options** --> **Xamarin** --> **Apple Account**. If you are not login, you can add you apple ID here. After login, you can choose your app ID  and then click **View Detail** button, you can see all the certifications you download or not download there.

Once your colleague download the **provisioning profile** and install properly, he will see the **provisioning profile** in his Visual Studio.

Refer: [manual-provisioning?tabs=windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?tabs=windows)

Comment: Yes, this worked. We had to generate a code signing certificate and provisioning profile.

Comment: Sadly it appears on VS 16.6 you have to delete and re-add your Apple account (under tools/options/Xamarin/Apple Account) for the Teams to update (if using Automatic Provisioning). So even if you have been added to a Team and have appropriate certs/etc the Team will not show up and never refreshes.

Answer (score 1):

First he should check if he is logged in with his Apple ID to Visual Studio - he needs to have Apple Developer ID to have any kind of provisional profile signing.

But even then I don't think that it will work, App ID is unique so if your team owns it no one else can have the same and thus it can't be created on his Apple account.

Comment: I can understand that we need to add him to our Team if he wants to create a Provisioning Profile, add a device to it, and deploy to that device.  But here he is building for the Simulator, and so should have an automatic Provisioning Profile available.

Comment: Well if you don't believe me tell him to change your app id in the info.plist and see if it works.

Comment: Do you mean change to a different app id (Bundle Identifier)?

Comment: Yes, also check if he is logged in to VS with Apple ID, I updated the answer with that

Comment: He has the same problem with a blank, new app created in Visual Studio. He is not logged in to Visual Studio with an Apple ID.

Comment: Then that is the problem, auto signing can't work without Apple ID data. But as said the next likely problem is that he will need to be a part of your team.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185721/discussion-between-james-lavery-and-ivan-icin).